# Does WP search natively return results sorted by type (post, post type, page, category...)?

Tags: search, sort

I found many solutions to sort search results by type, yet in default WP theme twentythirteen (and probably any other), search results seem to be already sorted by type. I would like to get confirmation that native WP search indeed sorts results by type and if so how does it do that?

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134833/73

Comment: Well it doesn't mention any sorting by post type by default, I don't understand why I get this sorting without doing anything.