# Separating search results collectively by type

Tags: search

My search results are limited to post types `book` and `author`. The following code in `search.php` displays all `author` posts first, then all `book` posts (I [asked](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135595/does-wp-search-natively-return-results-sorted-by-type-post-post-type-page-ca) why post types are separated like that, but got no answer so far):

```
while(have_posts()) : the_post();       
    if ( 'book-author' == get_post_type() ) {   
        ?>
        <h2>AUTHOR</h2>
        <?php the_title(); 
    }
    elseif ( 'book' == get_post_type() ) {  
        ?>
        <h2>BOOK</h2>
        <?php the_title(); 
    }
endwhile;
```

However I want to display these search results in two columns entitled "BOOKS" and "AUTHORS", each in its own `div` element. This code doesn't allow that, so how can I achieve such division?

Comment: could you clarify a bit... you say that posts are grouped by type as they should, what is the problem then? just wrap them in divs and apply style that puts them in columns next to eachother... or am i missing something

Comment: I see no way to do that with the code I pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two options.

The first and probably the easiest option is to run the query twice on the page in each place you want to use it.

```
// Author Block
while(have_posts()) : the_post();       
    if ( 'book-author' == get_post_type() ) {   
        ?>
        <h2>AUTHOR</h2>
        <?php the_title(); 
    }
endwhile; rewind_posts();

// Book Block
while(have_posts()) : the_post();       
    if ( 'book' == get_post_type() ) {  
        ?>
        <h2>BOOK</h2>
        <?php the_title(); 
    }
endwhile;
```

Note: I've used `rewind_posts()` after the first loop which resets the post counter.

The second option would be either filter the query that WordPress [executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275574/wordpress-ordering-multiples-post-types) or sorting the results once you have them, however for this solution you should be fine with the above code.