# Use pre_get_posts to display search results by meta in specific order

Tags: search, pre-get-posts

I have a search query that I'm limiting to search within a custom post type. When the content is returned I have it sorting by meta value. The post meta is a person's position.

The function below works as expected, but I need to pull the posts and sort them in a certain order.

```
function kg_search_filter( $query ) {

    if( is_search() && ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $initial = ( !empty( $_GET['pro_search_initial'] ) ) ? $_GET['pro_search_initial'] : "";
        $expertise = ( !empty( $_GET['pro_search_expertise'] ) ) ? $_GET['pro_search_expertise'] : "";
        $office = ( !empty( $_GET['pro_search_office'] ) ) ? $_GET['pro_search_office'] : "";

        $query->set( 'post_type', array('professional') );

        if( $office ) {
            $query->set( 'tax-location', $office );
        }

        if ( $expertise ) {
            $query->set( 'tax-expertise', $expertise );
        }

        if ( $initial ) {
            $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
                        array(
                              'key' => 'professional_last_initial',
                              'value' => $initial,
                              'compare' => '='
                        )
                    ));
        }

        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'professional_position');
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value');
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC');
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'kg_search_filter' );
```

What I'm after: First show all people with a president title, then all vice presidents, then the remaining.

I know I can use multiple loops as [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135656/separating-search-results-collectively-by-type/135665#135665) suggests, but I'm not sure how to implement the second suggestion using pre_get_posts in reference to my query.

Comment: you're already ordering by another meta key? you can't use multiple loops if the results are paginated, you'll only sort a single page's results. it looks like you'll need to modify the SQL directly.

Comment: The meta key order can be removed. It was there for initial testing. I'll look into modifying direct SQL calls.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of *same* meta field values being relative to each other isn't native to WordPress.

On top of my head you could create second meta field, which would express that relativeness as a number. So president is `1`, vice president `2` and so on. This would be a pain to adjust if the hierarchy changes in future though.

Comment: Thanks for that. The hierarchy shouldn't change. The metabox for title is a simple text field. One option I'm considered is setting orderby to menu_order and letting the user control order via the admin post menu with drag and drop.

Comment: You don't have to make user control numerical values, you can do that with code depending on "friendly" value user sets. Also why is it a text field? If the title is freeform it would be hard to maintain hierarchy.

Comment: The text field does present some difficulty. I wasn't given an specific list, so I opted to keep it freeform.